# Crossreferencing two SQL results, finding overlap?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a table of customer orders: inside are zero cost orders (things I have given away to customers) as well as paid orders. I want to find out how many customers who have received a free order have also purchased an order.

```
    SELECT customer_id
        FROM orders
        WHERE total = 0
        GROUP BY customer_id

    SELECT customer_id
        FROM orders
        WHERE total != 0
        GROUP BY customer_id
```

These two queries give me a list of customers who received a free order and a list of customers who paid for an order. I want to count the overlapping instances, for example:

```
//free orders
1,5,2,9,3,11,7
//paid orders
1,5,4,8,7,9,3,12,10,13
```

The intersect between these two sets is `{1,5,9,3,7}`, which is five element. I need a way to do this strictly using SQL preferred.

Comment: I rolled it back because I've been told in the past to specify I am using PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `having` clause.  This is probably the simplest way, assuming `total` has no negative values:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MIN(total) = 0 AND MAX(total) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested, sorry)

```
SELECT count(distinct customer_id)
    FROM orders a JOIN orders b
    ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    WHERE a.total = 0 and b.total <>0
```